# Trying to store Reverse string pattern into key value pair not working (Burrows Wheeler Rotation)

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, burrows-wheeler-transform

[image]

So I am trying to achieve this index (int) and data (string) into a Dictionary class which takes an index and data of above mentioned types. Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
     dict[i].setIndex(i);
     for (int j = i; j <= size; j++){
          dict[i].data += input[j];
     }
}
```

This code works fine for small text files of <10KiB but when I input large files of texts the loop seems to run forever. It keeps running until the whole memory is used and then crashed the IDE. What am I doing wrong here/or is there a way to optimize this process?

Edit: Here size variable refers to input.length().

Comment: A [mcve] instead of your snippet might be more helpful. However, a shot into blue: The outer loop iterates until `size - 1`: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` but the inner loop until `size`: `for (int j = i; j <= size; j++){`. Without knowing the rest, this could be an out-of-bound-access (or be fully correct), but, at least, it looks suspicious to me.

Comment: There is no way to make this dictionary significantly faster, and no way to make it more space-efficient, though, to implement Burrows-Wheeler Rotation you do not need this dictionary to sort rotations of the string (which, I assume, you a trying to do). If you are intending to sort the rotations of the string it is an entirely different question.

Comment: @Svistunov I am sorting the Dictionary using the heap sort declared in Dictionary class. It works fine. But the problem is with this specific loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to sort the suffices, you should use the suffix array, which is designed to solve this problem efficiently. Instead of storing the suffices themselves it stores the indices where the suffix starts. Whenever you would try to store all the suffices themselves you would use `O(n^2)`, making such code impossible to run on larger inputs.

It ordered these indices as follows. Instead of sorting suffixes themselves, it sorts the cyclic rotations of the string. Let's extend the word's substring meaning to work with cyclic strings, allowing us to use starting positions after the ending ones. Notice that any substring of size `2k` can be expressed as a concatenation of two substrings of size `k`. Therefore, under the assumption that we have already sorted all substrings of size `k`, we can sort substrings of size `2k` by comparing a pair with just two comparisons, for each half of the substring. Therefore, doubling the processed substring length can be done in `O(n log n)` time if using comparison-based sorts, or, in this case, even in `O(n)` using, for example, counting sort. Sorting substrings of length one is trivial.

Therefore, the final algorithm would be this: sort all the substrings of size one. Then until you have sorted long enough strings, double the size of the sorted substrings. This doubling can repeat only `O(log n)` times, meaning that the whole algorithm runs in `O(n log n)` time and uses `O(n)` space. You would end up with an array of indices of starting positions of suffices, ordered by the suffix they represent. With such representation, you can easily get the last character of the rotated string (`ans[(suffixIndex + n - 1) % n]`), or any other part of the string.

[This page](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-array.html#toc-tgt-3) has more details about this algorithm and provides an implementation in C++ language

Comment: This loop runs before sorting the suffix array as I mentioned above. This loop is only for obtaining the array.

Comment: @MuhammadIqbal you should not obtain the array itself, it would always be too slow, it uses size * size memory, so if you have 10kB of input data, your dictionary would weigh a magnitude of 100MB, and a 1MB text would result in a terabyte required to store your dictionary. There is no way around it with your approach, it is just the size of the text itself. This is not only space inefficient, but also slow. With the proposed algorithm you only need size * log(size) time, so for a megabyte input it would be faster by 5-6 orders of magnitude, and also it is a linear space algorithm.

Comment: Is there a code for your algorithm which would help me further to understand this?